# Characterisation of $\Sigma_m$ in the Arithmetic hierarchy.

Tags: computability, recursion

I have a question on the arithmetic hierarchy. Suppose I have a relation $R\in\Delta_{m}$, is it true that the set
$$
x\in A\iff\exists y R(x,y)
$$
lies in $\Sigma_m$?

Comment: No, $A$ will be in $\Sigma_m$.

Comment: Oops sorry, typo... Meant to write $\Sigma_m$. If $R$ were in $\Pi_{m-1}$ this would be true, but what if we only assumed $R\in\Delta_m$?

Comment: Then it's true, and you don't even need that $R\in\Delta_m$; it suffices that $R\in\Sigma_m$. The reason is that, if you express $R$ with a string of $m$ alternating quantifiers, beginning with an existential quantifier, followed by a recursive relation (the normal form for $\Sigma_m$), then that beginning quantifier in $R$ and the $\exists y$ in the definition of $A$ can be merged into a single quantifier by means of a recursive pairing function.

Comment: Ah, that turned out to be easier than expected. Thanks!